# Access a method from an object inside of another method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

imagine having this object :

```
var a = {
   b : () => console.log("yo"),
   c : () => b()
}
```

How can I execute the b function calling the c one ?
the syntax above doesn't work...
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: `a.b()` should do it.

Comment: but I don't want to use it by this way because i export an object from a file in nodejs..

Comment: Then you need to turn those arrow functions into standard functions, and use `this.b()`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = {
   b : () => console.log("yo"),
   c : () => a.b() // reference to the object
}
```

or

```js
var a = {
   b : () => console.log("yo"),
   c : function () {return this.b()} // use function syntax instead of lambda to gain a reference to the object on which c() is called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works?

```js
const a = {
  b : () => {console.log("yo")},
  c : () => {a.b()}
}

a.c()
```

Comment: yes, tanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrow functions use non-arrow functions, and then `this` will be available, if the method is called in the usual way:

```js
var a = {
   b() { console.log("yo") },
   c() { return this.b() }
}

a.c();
```

Answer (score 0):

make an actual class:

```
function A() {
  this.b = () => console.log('yo');
  this.c = () => this.b()
}

var a = new A();

a.c();
```